# How to delay fire and smoke animation?

Tags: animation, keyframes, timeline, filmic-blender

[image][image]
I have 3 animations on my movie: broke, fire, and smoke. I want the broke first, then fire, then smoke, but they are all starting at the same time. How to delay fire and smoke animation? You can see from the gif, as the plane is going to the ground, the ground fire is already burning. I just want the fire to burn when my plane crashes. i want to delay fire and smoke. how can i do that?

i did make a video for you. because my English is not good. look this video. i want to fire animation be active when plane arrive the graund. if you watch the video you can understand better me. look this video. youtube.com/watch?v=YS1LRsoSh7w&feature=youtu.be  if i change destinity and flame rate just animation smoke and fire not showing but moving. i want to animation delay when plane arrive the graund. and active.

youtube.com/watch?v=YS1LRsoSh7w&feature=youtu

Comment: Use two Smoke Domains and, under Smoke Cache settings, set your start frames appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blender let's us animate almost any value that we can alter. To get the results you want, you need to animate the values that change the effect you want.

To keyframe a value, go to the frame you want to set the value and with the mouse over the value press <kbd>I</kbd> or right click and choose *Insert Keyframe*. The value will get shaded in yellow to indicate the value is keyframed on the current frame or green to indicate it is keyed on another frame.

At frame 19 keyframe smoke density at 1.0 and keyframe flame rate as 0.0.

[image: smoke]

At frame 20 set density to 0.0 and flame rate to 2.0 and keyframe both.

[image: flames]

Re-bake the simulation.

Now you only get smoke until frame 20 when you start getting flames. Keyframe other values to get the variations you want at various times. Note that for the simulation, you need to allow a few frames for the smoke/fire to disperse as it doesn't just disappear when you turn it off, you only turn off the smoke/fire being emitted.

Comment: Bro i did make a video for you. because my English is not good. look this video. i want to fire animation be active when plane arrive the graund. if you watch the video you can understand better me. because i cant talk good English. look this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YS1LRsoSh7w&feature=youtu.be 

if i change destinity and flame rate just animation smoke and fire not shoving but moving. i want to animation wait when plane arrive the graund. and active.

Comment: You need to keyframe the values so that the flames are disabled until the time that you want them to start. Notice the density has a yellow background.

Comment: [Here is a quick example](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3938/) showing the animated values to go from smoke to flame and back to smoke again.

Comment: Hi sambler. i did look into your animation. but my problem is not fire color or smoke color. i need to delay my explosion+fire+smoke until plane arrive the graund. you can watch this video: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YS1LRsoSh7w&feature=youtu) 
graund fire already burning but plane did not arrive the graund.

Comment: A `Density` setting of `0.0` means no smoke, a `Flame Rate` of `0.0` means no flames, you animate those values to turn the flames and smoke on/off at the frames you want. Notice those values in the above screenshots are shown in yellow, that is blender colouring them to show they are animated, I only added the red box.

Comment: ohhh i understand you. and i did understand my quastion is wrong. because i have a not just a smoke look the video (0:29) [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YS1LRsoSh7w&feature=youtu) there is a explosion+smoke. smoke is not showing but explosion is already active. it is moving. but you answer the "How to delay fire and smoke animation?" ok. thank you. i will ask new quastion. this name will be "How to delay explosion animation." thanks a lot.